# Show image and text side by side in thymaleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to show image and then rows of text side by side. Such that image is on the left side and 2 lines of text are on its right side.
I want to do this in thymaleaf. Please find my code below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title th:remove="all">Template for HTML email with inline image</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="(${name})"></p>
    <p th:text="(${subject})"></p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src='cid:coupons' /></td>
            <tr>
            <td><h4>Login Url :</h4></td>
            <td>
                <h4 th:text="${loginurl}"></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>ID :</h4></td>
            <td>
                <h4 th:text="${id}"></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        Regards, <br /> <em>Admin</em>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is printing the image first and the lines below it. Can anyone please help how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you may try to insert in second `td` cell inner table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='cid:coupons' /></td>
    <td><table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Login Url :</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4 th:text="${loginurl}"></h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4>ID :</h4></td>
    <td>
      <h4 th:text="${id}"></h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But better solution to do it in `div` tags and make layout and style by adding `css` classes. Look at this [article](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/4-different-html-css-layout-techniques-to-create-a-site-85i9t1x34)